# File in unsupported text encoding?

Tags: macos, file, encryption, mp3

I was planning to try an do a parser for an mp3 file, so I opened terminal and did `code Desktop/music.mp3`. When I looked at the MP3 file to look at the format, it said file is in unsupported encoding. So when I took a look at the file, I instead got this jumbled up piece of question symbols.

[image: Image here]

I also tried looking at other files, and it all showed the same patterns.

Does anyone know what encoding this may be? My OS system is Mac, version High Sierra. I looked into it, and I believe it might be Mac's FileVault. I also plan on parsing other kinds of files. If I am not able to decode it, is there any method to open the file's text? Thank you.

Comment: If you think it is FileValut you can always turn that off to see if that is what it is, but I highly doubt its FileVault.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a ["binary" file/format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) and a text one.

Answer (score 1):

The files don't contain ASCII/text so you can't look at them in a text editor. A breakdown of the file format can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3

Comment: I plan to do this with other files too. Is there any other way to find the format of a file?

Comment: @robby Files have different file extensions *usually* to represent the format they are in.  MP3 files are in MP3 file format.  The rule extends quite well for binary files.  A lot of formats have "magic bytes" at the start.  This can help identify an unknown file format.